# Alternatives to fprintd

Tags: linux-mint, kde, fingerprint

My fingerprint reader (27c6:55a2) is currently not supported with `fprintd`.
Are there any good alternatives supporting my reader?

I am using Mint with KDE, I used to have Windows 11, which used Windows Hello and it worked well.

Comment: There is no alternative.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.